# How to fix the progress bar while playing youtube video?

Tags: youtube

Youtube progress bar and (red bar) and the current position (45:17/2:36:00) disappears after three seconds or if I move the mouse cursor out of the video window.

Can I fix the progress bar or current position on top of the screen while I scroll down to read the replies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you scroll down to read the replies, then the video window is not visible, so freezing the progress bar does not make sense. Maybe you want to show separate progress bar even though the video itself is not visible. This feature is not provided. There may be a Chrome extention with such a feature. As fas as I know, there is no such an extension as of December 22, 2022.

Answer (score 0):

You also asked the progress bar when you are still watching the video.

It is not possible in the desktop web browser.

On the other hand, the red progress bar is always on as you want in the YouTube mobile web for Android as of December 22, 2022.